# Filtering SpaCy noun_chunks by pos_tag

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, chunks, pos-tagger

As the subj line says, I'm trying to extract elements of noun_chunks based on their individual POS tags. It seems that elements of a noun_chunk do not have access to the global sentence POS tags.

To demonstrate the issue:

```py
[i.pos_ for i in nlp("Great coffee at a place with a great view!").noun_chunks]
>>> 
AttributeError: 'spacy.tokens.span.Span' object has no attribute 'pos_'
```

Here is my inefficient solution:

```py
def parse(text):
    doc = nlp(text.lower())
    tags = [(idx,i.text,i.pos_) for idx,i in enumerate(doc)]

    chunks = [i for i in doc.noun_chunks]

    indices = []
    for c in chunks:
        indices.extend(j for j in range(c.start_char,c.end_char))
    non_chunks = [w for w in ''.join([i for idx,i in enumerate(text) if idx not in indices]).split(' ') 
                  if w != '']

    chunk_words = [tup[1] for tup in tags if tup[1] not in non_chunks and tup[2] not in ['DET','VERB','SYM','NUM']] #these are the POS tags which I wanted to filter out from the beginning!

    new_chunks = []
    for c in chunks:
        new_words = [w for w in str(c).split(' ') if w in chunk_words]
        if len(new_words) > 1:
            new_chunk = ' '.join(new_words)
            new_chunks.append(new_chunk)
    return new_chunks

parse(
"""
I may be biased about Counter Coffee since I live in town, but this is a great place that makes a great cup of coffee. I have been coming here for about 2 years and wish I would have found it sooner. It is located right in the heart of Forest Park and there is a ton of street parking. The coffee here is great....many other words could describe it, but that sums it up perfectly. You can by coffee by the pound, order a hot drink, and they also have food. On the weekend, there are donuts brought in from Do-Rite Donuts which have almost a cult like following. The food is a little on the high end price wise, but totally worth it. I am a self admitted latte snob and they make an amazing latte here. You can add skim, whole, almond or oat milk and they will make it happen. I always order easy foam and they always make it perfectly. My girlfriend loves the Chai Latte with Oat Milk and I will admit it is pretty good. Give them a try.
""")

>>>
['counter coffee',
 'great place',
 'great cup',
 'forest park',
 'street parking',
 'many other words',
 'hot drink',
 'almost cult',
 'high end price',
 'latte snob',
 'amazing latte',
 'oat milk',
 'easy foam',
 'chai latte',
 'oat milk']
```

Any quicker approaches to the same solution would be welcomed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't work:

```
[i.pos_ for i in nlp("Great coffee at a place with a great view!").noun_chunks]
```

because `noun_chunks` returns `Span` objects, not `Token` objects.

You can get to the POS tags within each noun chunk by iterating over the tokens:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
for i in nlp("Great coffee at a place with a great view!").noun_chunks:
    print(i, [t.pos_ for t in i])
```

which will give you

```
Great coffee ['ADJ', 'NOUN'] 
a place ['DET', 'NOUN'] 
a great view ['DET', 'ADJ', 'NOUN']
```

Comment: My god, that was so simple and easy. You're a hero!

Comment: I was doing all kinds of janky things to get this and was finally fed up and hoping to find a simpler way in a newer version perhaps. Never even occurred to me to take this approach. Thanks 100x

Comment: Happy to hear it was useful to you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Original credit to this link:
[Phrase extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39100652/python-chunking-others-than-noun-phrases-e-g-prepositional-using-spacy-etc)

```
 def get_nns(doc):
        nns = []
        for token in doc:
            # Try this with other parts of speech for different subtrees.
            if token.pos_ == 'NOUN':
                pp = ' '.join([tok.orth_ for tok in token.subtree])
                nns.append(pp)
        return nns

 import spacy
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
    ex = 'I am having a Great coffee at a place with a great view!'
    doc = nlp(ex)
    print(get_nns(doc))
```

Output:

```
['a Great coffee', 'a place with a great view', 'a great view']
```